# How to get folder from OSGI bundle?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, eclipse-jdt

I have own OSGI bundle that have folder inside with some resources. How to read that folder from bundle and get all children of it?

I used before following code.:

```
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(bundleID);
    URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry(templatePath);
    URL url = FileLocator.resolve(fileURL);
```

This code workd utils I exported Eclipse application as Eclipse product.

But I have URL is not hierachical excepiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the findEntries method on Bundle to locate files in the bundle and any attached fragments:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(bundleID);
Enumeration<URL> urls = bundle.findEntries("/folder", "*", false);
```

Comment: Hi Nick. I have a similar problem [**HERE** : *How to copy a resource directory and all included files and sub-folders in a Jar onto another directory*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400436/how-to-copy-a-resource-directory-and-all-included-files-and-sub-folders-in-a-jar). How can I go about copying a resource directory from an OSGi bundle onto another Directory? How can I go about implementing the option you gave here to this end? I will be very grateful if you could help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your code in terms of InputStreams and use the method suggested by [@NickWilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257372/nick-wilson) to retrieve the input streams and use them in your program.

But if you really need that folder exploded on the disk somewhere, you would use *org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(URL)* instead of *resolve(URL)*.